# Disable VSTO signing on different configuration

Tags: c#, vsto, code-signing

I have a Excel Addin (VSTO) written in C# using Visual Studio 2017.

My organization is using a code signing certificate from Symantec that is stored on a USB drive. The USB drive is attached to a build machine that I can not access during the development.
I've configured my VSTO to be signed during the build in project settings as shown in the picture.
[image]
My problem is that on development machines, I dont have the access to the certificate, so the build fails.

My ideal solution would be to disable the code signing in DEBUG configuration, but such thing would disable the signing for all configuration.
Did anyone experience such problem?

Answer (score 2):

Create a self-signed certificate for developer use giving it the same name as the production certificate, feel free to even have it checked into source control.  Modify the project file to have a custom build step only for **Debug** configurations that will sign using standard techniques (not utilising signing tools from say Symantec) but with the self-signed cert.  You may be able to do it in the UI otherwise modify the .csproj directly to include a custom msbuild step.

The Build server will continue to build and sign with whatever means you have now, including with the certificate on the USB stick.  This will allow the CI server to build and sign officially whilst keeping the certificate secret.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible since the certificate is located on the USB drive (SafeNet eToken). The process is able to sign the EXE only when the USB is attached.

Comment: @EylM Ah I slightly misinterpreted sorry.  Please see update